# Store EditText in an array and display in a TextView

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am trying to store my EditTexts in an array and display all of them in a TextView, then have a sum function to get the sum of the array and display the sum. But I am stuck at this point.

```
public void Clickme (View view) {
   public void clickMe (View v){
    //my EditText’s ID is called myInput
        EditText myInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myInput);
    //my TextView’s ID is called text2
        TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
        String str = myInput.getText().toString();
        text2.setText(str);
        int [] array = new int [myInput.length()];
        //I am stuck at this point
        for(int i=0; i <myInput.length(); i++) {
            array[i] = Integer.valueOf(myInput.getText(i));
        }
       //sum function
       for (int i: array) {
        str = str + i;
        EditText.setText(str);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a method in a method... That won't compile

```
public void Clickme (View view) {
   public void clickMe (View v){
```

And what are you trying to do here? `EditText.setText(str);`

`setText` is not a static method.

> then have a sum function to get the sum of the array and display the sum

And here? `str = str + i;`

That isn't a sum of numbers. You are appending a number to a string.

And this method doesn't exist... `myInput.getText(i)`

---

Based on your loop and array creation, looks like you want to add all the digits of a number.

```
private EditText myInput;
private TextView text2;

public void onCreate(Bundle b) {
    super.onCreate(b);
    setContentView(...);
    ...

    myInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myInput);
    text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2);
} 

public void clickMe (View view) {
    String input = myInput.getText().toString();
    int number = 0;
    if (!input.isEmpty()) {
        number = Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
    // Sum the digits in a number
    int sum = 0;
    while (number > 0) {
        sum += number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    text2.setText(String.valueOf(sum));
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir. This is really helpful.